# php exception handling with error reporting on

Tags: php, exception, error-handling

Consider this sample code:

```
<?    
try {
        throw new Exception('new');
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        echo "caught";
    }
?>
```

I assume this should just output the string "caught" when run. However, with display errors turned on, I see the exception shown on the web page like `( ! ) Exception: new in test.php on line 2` along with a dump of call stack and variables in scope.

With display errors off, it doesn't show the exception notice. Shouldn't the try catch block prevent the notice to be shown even with display errors on?

Comment: What you quote doesn't look like the ordinary PHP error reporting. Do you have a custom error handler registered in your script?

Comment: No.. I just have ini_set('display_errors',1); at the beginning of the script.

Comment: And that `( ! )` is in the error message? Literally? Strange.

Comment: Ya, it shows (!) before the exception notice. Aren't you able to replicate this with ini_set('display_errors',1); ?

Comment: which version of PHP do you have? The code you provided runs fine on my system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using xdebug and you do not want to disable xdebug or error reporting and you do not want trace messages of caught exceptions to appear, you can turn off the display of the exception trace with

```
xdebug.show_exception_trace = 0
```

in your php.ini